# PHP: INSERT array to table with a timer or clock (per second)

Tags: php

I would like to know if it is possible to insert values from array to a table, one by one, per second(or based on the clock). Any reference would do. What I could do is insert the whole array immediately only to the table.

Additional: would it be possible to pause the process? example when I click the pause button the clock will stop together with the arrays inserting into the table.

I am trying to create a project that would create a cpu job scheduler (MLQ). It would require viewing how each jobs are inserted to each queue and decrements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With javascript `setInterval()` method calls a function at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

```
var pause = setInterval(function(){ insert data }, 2000); // 2 sec
```

To stop the time use  `clearInterval(pause)` by referencing the variable.

To execute the function once use `setTimeout()`